# A contribution batch containing transactions of more than one currencies causes fatal error

Tags: civicontribute, ajax, batches, currency

My setup: CiviCRM 5.18.3 on Drupal 7.

I created a Contribution batch.
At transactions I chose two transactions of difference currencies e.g. HKD and USD and Assign them to a batch.
Then I no longer be able to retrieve the list of batches because of fatal error:
Dialog:
DataTables warning: table id=crm-batch-selector-2 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

In ConfigAndLog there are lines produced e.g. CRM_Core_Exception .... Invalid currency "HKD,USD" blah blah.....

Even I cancel the offending transaction it does not help. I had to delete the transaction in that batch to revive the batch's functioning.

Please kindly advise.

Best Regards,

```
2019-10-17 (too long to add to comments).
I copied this from ConfigAndLog, because no on-screen backtrace is shown even I enabled backtrace at System setting.
Oct 17 09:53:08  [debug] $backTrace = #0
/var/www/c53/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(463): 
 CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

#1 /var/www/c53/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(55): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))

#2 /var/www/c53/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(444): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

#3 /var/www/c53/web/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "batchlist")

#4 /var/www/c53/web/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()

#5 {main}
```

Comment: Did this work previously? I know contribution batches have been reworked recently.  Also - please add the full error and backtrace to your question, it helps folks to diagnose the problem!

Comment: More info: If I put the expected amount for the batch, the error appears as soon as I assign a contribution of a different currency. If I leave the expected amount empty, the error appears when I close the batch. Then I am no longer able to retrieve a list of closed batch.

Comment: Added backtrace at main post.

Comment: @Jon G megaphone. I am still evaluating so no prior working history. But I first encountered this problem with version 5.17.4. Then I upgraded to the latest 5.18.3 just to see the same problem still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the standard workflow for accounting requires a single currency per batch. At least that was all that we aimed to support. Please create an issue at lab.civicrm.org indicating that there should be a 'friendly' error message preventing transactions that have a different currency from ones already in the batch from being added. This should include an error in case of an attempt to simultaneously add transactions in more than one currency.

Comment: Posted at [link](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/89)

Comment: Thanks, @KLeeHK. I've assigned the issue to myself, but I'm not sure when I will be able to prioritize it. Cheers.